# Get array child from recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have variable with child from database. So for example:

```
$roots = $this->getCategoryTable()->getCategoryRoot($project_id);//themes

            if($roots->count()> 0){
                foreach($roots as $root){
                    $root_id = $root->id;

                    //show name root
                    echo $root->name;

                    //show children of root
                    if($this->getCategoryTable()->checkHasRowsChildren($root_id)){
                        $rootChild = $this->getCategoryTable()->getRowsChildren($root_id);
                        if($rootChild->count() > 0){
                            foreach($rootChild as $key => $val) {
                                $array_themes[]=$val->name;
                                $result = $this->getChild($val->id, $array_themes);
                            }//end of foreach child of root
                        }//end of existing child of root 
                    }

                }//end of foreach root
            }//end of existing root
```

and this is my function to get children

```
function getChild($root_id, $array_themes) {
    if($this->getCategoryTable()->checkHasRowsChildren($root_id)){
        $rootChild = $this->getCategoryTable()->getRowsChildren($root_id);
        if($rootChild->count() > 0){
            foreach($rootChild as $key => $val) {
                $array_themes[]=$val->name;
                $this->getChild($val->id, $array_themes);
            }//end of foreach child of root
        }//end of existing child of root 
    }
}
```

And The result should be like this:

Child : Parent

H : G
G : D
J : C
F : C
C : A
B : A
A : E
E : D
D : Null

I was get all parent and child. But in the end result that I want to get result array like

```
  $array_result = array(
        [0]=>"D",
        [1]=>"E",
        [2]=>"A",
        [3]=>"C",
        [4]=>"F",
        [5]=>"J",
        [6]=>"G",
        [7]=>"H"
  );
```

it is possible to get array result like that?

Comment: Please, show how the source (original) array looks

Comment: $array_result = array(
        [0]=>"H"
  );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are quite close to the solution, you only need to add who is the parent of the current child, with (changes in nested foreach) :

```
$roots = $this->getCategoryTable()->getCategoryRoot($project_id);//themes

if($roots->count()> 0){
    foreach($roots as $root){
        $root_id = $root->id;

        //show name root
        echo $root->name;

        //show children of root
        if($this->getCategoryTable()->checkHasRowsChildren($root_id)){
            $rootChild = $this->getCategoryTable()->getRowsChildren($root_id);
            if($rootChild->count() > 0){
                foreach($rootChild as $key => $val) {
                    //CHANGES IN HERE
                    //SINCE THIS IS THE TOP, THERE ARE NO PARENT ( = NULL)
                    $array_themes[] = array('child' => $val->name, 'parent' => NULL); //MULTIDIMENSIONNAL ARRAY
                    $result = $this->getChild($val, $array_themes); // PASSING $val ENTIRELY TO KEEP PARENT NAME IN FUNCTION
                }//end of foreach child of root
            }//end of existing child of root 
        }

    }//end of foreach root
}//end of existing root
```

And in your getChild function, something like :

```
function getChild($root, $actualParent, $array_themes) {
    //SINCE NOW IT'S $root AND NOT ONLY id, YOU NEED TO UPDATE A LITTLE
    if($this->getCategoryTable()->checkHasRowsChildren($root->id)){
        $rootChild = $this->getCategoryTable()->getRowsChildren($root->id);
        if($rootChild->count() > 0){
            foreach($rootChild as $key => $val) {
                $array_themes[] = array('child' => $val->name, 'parent' => $root->name); // MULTIDIMENSIONNAL ARRAY
                $this->getChild($val, $array_themes); // STILL GIVING ALL $val
            }//end of foreach child of root
        }//end of existing child of root 
    }
}
```

With this, you should get a multidimensionnal array near what you want. You should note that the order you'll get is different from what you wanted, so you might need to make a few changes for this to work exactly how you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I only get the parent and children level 1 but not the another level. It is because $this->getChild on function getChild didn't call?

Comment: Maybe just calling `function getChild($root, $actualParent, &$array_themes)` (Passing by reference) and outputting `$array_themes` after your foreach root.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was add & in the front of variable to be &$array_themes and it working now.

Comment: No problem, remember that you could have gone with a `var $array_themes = array();` in your Class, and then calling it by `$this->array_themes` instead of `$array_themes`. Might be better, depending on your use.